# Flutter Cannot build release APK file on flutter:1.12.13+hotfix.8

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, apk

Flutter Cannot build release APK file on flutter:1.12.13+hotfix.8

Hello dear, 
On flutter:1.12.13+hotfix.8, when I build release apk file get some error Like below:

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: try a clean build

Comment: Thank you Darish , I ready try flutter clean and rebuild build again, but it not solve these problem.

Comment: How many languages in your app?

Comment: Hello  Jay Kikani, I have only one Language in my project.

Comment: Who can answer me, please help..!